# Extract a part of Series

Tags: series-expansion

If I have the output of Series, in terms of powers of my variable $x$, what is the quickest way to extract a part of the series, say for example the terms from $x^2$ to $x^5$, excluding those with lower and higher powers of $x$?

Answer (score 3):

```
ser=Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

> $ 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^7}{5040}+\frac{x^8}{40320}+\frac{x^9}{362880}+\frac{x^{10}}{3628800}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$

```
Normal[ser][[3;;5]]
```

> $ \frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2} $

Or

```
spartsF = FromDigits[Reverse[#[[3, #2 + 1 ;; #3 + 1]]], #[[1]]] #[[1]]^(#2) &;
spartsF[ser, 2, 4]
```

> $x^2 \left(\frac{x^2}{24}+\frac{x}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Or

```
spartF2 = With[{s = #, r = ##2}, Plus @@ (SeriesCoefficient[s, {x, 0, #}] x^# & /@ Range[r])] &;
spartF2[ser, 2, 4]
```

> $\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}$

Comment: This looks very simple, thanks! But it doesn't help when there also are fractionary powers of $x$ in the series... Is there a way to make it work as SeriesCoefficient?

Comment: @usumdelphini, please see the update.

Comment: The last two do not work for example for `x^(-1/2) + 2 x^-1 + 3 x^(-3/2) + 4 x^-2 + 5 x^(1/2) + x^1 + x^(3/2)`

Comment: @usumdelphini, i think for series with fractional powers the second one is not salvageable; i will see if the last one can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = Series[E^Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}] // Normal;

Cases[expr, a_.*x^n_?(2 <= # <= 5 &)] // Total
```

> x^2/2 - x^4/8 - x^5/15

Answer (score 1):

```
f=Normal[# + O[x]^(#2[[2]] + 1)] - Normal[# + O[x]^(#2[[1]])] &;

ser = Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}];

f[ser, {2,5}]

(* x^2/2 + x^3/6 + x^4/24 + x^5/120 *)
```

This handles series where powers are not sequential/predictable, where the nice and compact use of Part in other answers fails/becomes difficult to use:

```
ser = Series[Exp[2 x^2]*x, {x, 0, 10}]
f[ser, {3, 6}]

(*

x+2 x^3+2 x^5+(4 x^7)/3+(2 x^9)/3+O[x]^11

2 x^3 + 2 x^5

*)
```

Comment: This fails to work for expansions around $\infty$

Answer (score 0):

```
mySeries = Series[Exp[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{x^5}{15}-\frac{x^6}{240}+\frac{x^7}{90}+\frac{31
   x^8}{5760}+\frac{x^9}{5670}-\frac{2951 x^{10}}{3628800}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$

```
SeriesCoefficient[mySeries, #] & /@ Range[2, 5]
```

$\left\{\frac{1}{2},0,-\frac{1}{8},-\frac{1}{15}\right\}$

Comment: Thanks! And if I wanted the function, not only the coefficients?